# The Capability to choose post/page template

Tags: functions, user-roles, capabilities

I have created a role in wordpress with `add_role( string $role, string $display_name, array $capabilities = array() )`
function I want to know witch Capability from the array of `$capabilities` will give it access to choose post template?
the option is under Post Attributes section!

This is my code:

```
     $capabilities = array(
"activate_plugins" => false,
"create_users" => false,
"delete_themes" => false,
"delete_users" => false,
"edit_files" => false,
"edit_plugins" => false,
"edit_theme_options" => false,
"edit_themes" => false,
"edit_users" => false,
"export" => false,
"import" => false,
"install_plugins" => false,
"install_themes" => false,
"list_users" => false,
"manage_options" => false,
"promote_users" => false,
"remove_users" => false,
"switch_themes" => false,
"update_core" => false,
"update_plugins" => false,
"update_themes" => false,
"edit_dashboard" => false,
"customize" => false,
"delete_site" => false,
"moderate_comments" => false,
"manage_categories" => false,
"manage_links" => false,
"edit_others_posts" => true,
"edit_pages" => false,
"edit_others_pages" => false,
"edit_published_pages" => false,
"publish_pages" => false,
"delete_pages" => false,
"delete_others_pages" => false,
"delete_published_pages" => false,
"delete_others_posts" => true,
"delete_private_posts" => true,
"edit_private_posts" => true,
"read_private_posts" => true,
"delete_private_pages" => false,
"edit_private_pages"=> false,
"read_private_pages" => false,
"unfiltered_html"=> false,
"edit_published_posts"  => true,
"upload_files" => true,
"publish_posts" => true,
"delete_published_posts" => true,
"edit_posts" => true,
"delete_posts" => true,
"read" => true);
 add_role( "parisa", "parisa", $capabilities );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "choose post template"? That thing on the right (normal, video, link, ..)? I don't think there is an extra capability for that, people just need to be able to edit posts

Comment: in editor role (the dropdown list that you can choose from costume post templates that i have created) don`t show the post template option but in admin role I have it!
the option is under post attributes section

Comment: there is no capabilities that allow page edition and deny template metabox. have you look in the screen options if the metabox is just hidden ?

Answer (score 1):

A user with the capability of Create/Edit/Delete posts may access to choose post template.For more, please visit [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Hope this will helps you.